# LED bulb on outdoor light fixture blinking

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

I have two light fixtures outdoors connected to the same light switch.  Both of these fixtures are identical and have standard (USA) light bulb sockets.  Brand new LED light bulbs were installed in each fixture and all was good.  After a few months, one of the bulbs when turned on would always be consistently blinking.  Wanting to rule out an issue with the fixture, I connected the bulb to the other fixture as a test and it was flashing in that one as well so I assumed this was just a bad bulb.  The bulb was replaced ( same exact brand ) and all was good.  Fast forward another few months and the replacement bulb is now constantly blinking when on.

Is this just a coincidence that two different bulbs on the same fixture would start behaving this way or could there be an issue with the fixture that would cause this?

*EDIT* To answer some questions in the comments:

- The switch is an on/off timer switch
- The fixtures are not fully enclosed ( the bottom is completely open )
- The bulbs are Ecosmart (1004 865 468) and the box does say that they are suitable for wet locations as well as enclosed fixtures and uses only 8.5W

Comment: What brand/model of bulbs? Is the switch a simple On/Off or any of: Smart, Dimmer, Motion Detector, Timer, Dawn-to-Dusk?

Comment: In addition to lamp type, are they rated for wet locations? Water or condensation could be getting into one fixture.

Comment: I bet your particular bulbs are not labeled for fully enclosed fixtures, which is typical of outdoor fixtures. Your bulb repeatedly overheats until the main capacitor dries/pops, at which point the bulb can no longer boot up the DC power supply that feeds the actual LED; it won't "turn over" once that happens and the bulb needs replaced. Use smaller wattage and enclosure-approved bulbs.

Comment: Cheap junk from china led imports the number one problem is strobing or blinking sometimes when new sometimes when used for a while. The cheap components used in the drivers fail and the blinking starts. Getting lights that are DLC rated will cost more but the blinking will be solved in my experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`The bulb was replaced ( same exact brand )`.

Try something different.  I have a handful of the early LED models that have lasted many years, the ones with the heavy heat syncs on them, and some outdoor flood lights that are on nightly.  They aren't as bright as when I first got them, but they still work well.

The things they sell now, whether Great Value, or Utilitech, many of the cheaper models don't even last as long as an incandescent.  They all start failing by flickering.  I'd invest a bit more money into your LED choice to get the 25 years they are supposed to last.

Comment: Oddly enough I just pulled 2 dead Utilitech LEDs after answering this.  They don't even carry them at Lowes here anymore, only GE LEDs which guaranteed 5 years with free replacement warranty.  We'll see how that goes.